# What are the differece between these two forms of Ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This code is from tiztag tutorial

```
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "serverTime.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

This is another one I find throughout jQuery website:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET" // or "POST"
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  error: //function
});
```

I've been trying to use both ways to get some sort of response from PHP file.  The first example works but I also want to get the second form to work... could someone give me some guidance? In my php all i have is:

```
<?php
echo("Response from PHP");
?>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery? What do you see in the JS console?

Comment: check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example

Comment: "What do you see in the JS console?"

Comment: Did you store your js file on your server?

Comment: I'm rewriting the code from scratch and I store it on my computer, I'm using WAMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two is almost nothing. jQuery just prevents you from doing the extra boiler plate code surrounding the cross browser compatibility.

The [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation should give you all the information you need.

You will need to have an `url` variable, and a `success` variable.

The `url` variable will be a string to the URL in which you're trying to send this information.

The `success` variable will be a 'callback' function that will do whatever it is you're trying to do. It will ONLY be called if your call was a success.

Always check your Javascript console to see what your errors are.

Comment: If possible, could you explain what the differences are in between those 2 forms of ajax?

Comment: Just added a note to the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
 type:'GET' // or "POST"
 url: 'http://www.yoursite.com/yourPhpFile.php',
 data: 'some text',//Can  be multiple data using object
 success: function(data){
   alert(data);
 },
 error: function(){
   //Do something if an error is occurred
 }
});
```